# rawQuery() of sqlite throw IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

My Query is :

```
Cursor cursor = dbReader.rawQuery("SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = ?", new String[]{categoryTitle});
```

this result error:

```
<expr> expected, got '?'
```

I changed it to :

```
 Cursor cursor = dbReader.rawQuery("SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = '?'", new String[]{categoryTitle});
```

result exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

but when changed to :

```
Cursor cursor = dbReader.rawQuery("SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = '"+ categoryTitle+ "'", new String[]{});
```

it work with me....
What is the wrong in the two above query?

[This screenshot for first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFcHn.png)

Comment: Your query looks fine. Judging from your screenshot, looks like it is AS 3.0 thingy. just run the app, it should run fine.

Comment: I try to running but not work like screenshot ... Is there an error in  AS 3.0?

Comment: Is your query not giving you expected output or it is just not compiling?

Comment: Sorry My friend I try now to running it and it work fine but the red line error still appear

Answer (score 3):

In the second query: Variables should not be quoted. `'?'` should be `?` to be taken as a variable you can bind values to. `'?'` is a literal question mark and not a variable.

The first query is fine. The message

```
<expr> expected, got '?'
```

is not an error but rather just a warning from Android Studio that tries to validate your SQL but does not really know enough about SQL syntax. You can ignore that warning. There's already a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68403417) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a static final variable. Something like this:

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = ?"
...
Cursor cursor = dbReader.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{categoryTitle});
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer work fine and I try it but I want know what's the wrong in fist query as in screenshot

Comment: @amralsaidy there is nothing wrong with the query. The problem seems to come from the IDE as laalto said, it can't recognize the SQL query. So, I would say don't worry about it. Besides, hard coding is not a good practice, so you want to consider using a static final variable for this case :)

Answer (score 0):

`"SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = ?"` is a valid query.

Android Studio is not validating it as plain SQL but as [Room SQL](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

Room uses different placeholders and the query would look like this:

`"SELECT CategoryID FROM categories WHERE CategoryTitle = :title"`

You are not using room, so do not change it.

Also see this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68293745).

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you can just use backquote `?` and that will work fine. Because android studio tries to understand if that is a value or not. As ? can be applied only on values. Previously I had got the same error with my query but with the backquote the error just gone and works like a charm.